# Puzzle to identify shortest route

Tags: java, puzzle

Today I was going through a problem where we have to identify a shortest distance between a source and destination

There are many nodes say each node is a airport in a city(PSB the image) and count is the number of flights between the cities .Now I have to identify the shortest route between two given cities

Now the way I have thought of is I will take a hashMap which will store source city as key and destination city as value .

Now to identify the shortest route between two given cities what I will do is search the keyset to identify the entry object which contain the source city and search the destination city in the values of the HM like

My HM will be like (ref the image to understand the entries in the hm)

```
hm.put(h,b);
hm.put(b,c);
hm.put(c,e);
hm.put(b,e);
```

Now suppose I have been asked to identify the shortest route between h and e

As per my algorithm i will search the **keyset** of hm  for "h" city .

1) I will get `<h,b>` map entry object
    Now I will traverse the hm `valueSet` for "e" city. 
   2) I will get `<c,e>` and `<b,e>` map entry object

Now with the help of the entry.value which is `b` which I got from Step 1, i will try to associate the key from the entry object I got from Step 2 and thus i will identify that h-b-e is shorter distance compare to h-b-c-e

[image]

I not only wants to understand if there is any better solution to the problem but also i want to understand any book or link where I can get such kind of design problems.

Comment: Is your example even a valid path? Are the arrows in the image of any meaning?

Comment: Have a look at A* algorithm

Comment: Or have a look at Dijkstra algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at these two algorithms: [Djistrak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).
Your idea is basically quite nice, though it only works for smaller graphs and rather specific conditions.